# авторизация с помощью python requests

Tags: python, requests

Учусь создавать скрипты для авторизации на сайтах и дальнейшего выполнения рутинной работы. Использую python и библиотеку requests. Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте hh, сделал get запрос и достал из куки csrf, но не могу найти post и payload для авторизации, как это сделать с помощью панели разработчика chrome? (И если кто, разбирается, может подсказать материалы, для того, чтобы разобраться в различных механизмах авторизации и как с ними работать. Желательно без использования selenium)

Comment: Так у них API есть вроде бы https://dev.hh.ru/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, знаю что есть, но как я уже описал, мне необходим не один сайт и есть те, где API нет,  отчасти поэтому хочу научиться без таких вспомогательных инструментов реализовать функционал, отчасти из-за личного выбора и желания научиться:)

Comment: ну это только трафик анализировать где нет открытого API

Comment: Подскажите, а как этому научиться, есть какие-то материалы, я могу отслеживать через панель chrome запросы, но опять-таки, post найти не получается...

Comment: В русскоязычном сигменте с этим очень печально, а с аглийским у меня беда. Для трафика народ рекомендует Fiddler, сам пока по старинке в браузере копаюсь.

Comment: Как анализировать POST запросы в веб-браузере https://hackware.ru/?p=8973

Comment: Хоть что-то...
Благодарю)

Comment: А есть что-нибудь ещё, этого оказалось недостаточно( Хотя бы как правильно тему указать для того чтобы загуглить можно было, "Анализ трафика http с  помощью chrome"?

Comment: тогда уж лучше  "Анализ трафика http"